# How to decode JSON including \u escape characters as UTF8 NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, decode

I'm fetching JSON objects and saving them in NSString as follows:

```
// fetch JSON from a Wiki article
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

This is working in general but my responseString is full of `\u####` escape characters, what I want is the corresponding UTF8 characters, e.g. `\u2640` should be `♀`.

What's the easiest way to **decode all escape characters** in my `responseString`?

---

**UPDATE:** 
I read somewhere that I should try fetching the JSON with `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, but this lead to an error so I didn't get a `responseString` at all with this.

The error then is:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't fetch a *string*. Fetch *data* and convert is using `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

`NSJSONSerialization` handles all the quoting and escaping stuff automatically.

`jsonObject` will be an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, depending on the input data.

*Remark*: `dataWithContentsOfURL` blocks the current thread until the request is completely
finished (or timed out). If that is an issue, consider to use one of the asynchronous
methods of `NSURLConnection` to fetch the data.)

Comment: Uhh! About 20 seconds faster than me! +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I already wrote a parser for the `responseString` object (which contains ALL the JSON data) so I will need to have a way to make a single NSString from the `jsonObject` then. Do you know such a way?

Comment: OK, I found a way to get to the information I needed by using the `NSDictionary` object, thanks for the quick answer! :)